# Нужна ли запятая перед оборотом "и уж тем более"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Аня не знала, как можно водить автомобиль(,) и уж тем более, как его починить.*

*Аня не знала, что делали роботы(,) и уж тем более не знала, как починить их.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Аня не знала, как можно водить автомобиль и уж тем более как его починить.**

*Тем более* в вашем случае — частица, на знаки не влияет. *Уж* — усилительная частица, на знаки также не влияет. Поэтому для разбора имеем предложение:

> Аня не знала, как можно водить автомобиль и как его починить.

Это два однородных изъяснительных придаточных, подчинённых сказуемому *"не знала"*. Запятая не ставится.

**Аня не знала, что делали роботы, и уж тем более не знала, как починить их.**

Для разбора имеем предложение:

> Аня не знала, что делали роботы, и не знала, как починить их.

Здесь два сказуемых, хоть и одинаковых, к каждому из которых присоединено своё придаточное. По общему правилу придаточные выделяются запятыми, поэтому здесь первое придаточное (находящееся между однородными сказуемыми) выделено с обеих сторон.
Аналогичный пример: *Капустин обещал договориться с начальником школы, **чтобы он увеличил Мересьеву число вылетов**, и предложил Алексею самому составить себе программу тренировок (Пол.)*