Нужно ли обособление «тем более» в данном случае?
Нужно ли обособление "тем более" в таком предложении?
Если не хочешь быть убийцей и, тем более, самоубийцей, то вариант один — найти какую-то среднюю дорожку, несмотря на риски.

Похожая тема  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470140/Нужна-ли-запятая-перед-оборотом-и-уж-тем-более   Также Справочник https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/spravochnik-po-punktuatsii/tem-bolee  Также карта слов  https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словосочетанием/тем+более  Решение практически однозначное, вариантов нет

Может ли ТЕМ БОЛЕЕ быть вводным словом?
В Справочнике есть фраза:  В художественной литературе ВСТРЕЧАЮТСЯ примеры употребления слов «тем более» в роли вводных.
В каких еще источниках подтверждена эта функция?  В ПАС даже тем не менее указано как вводное, но тем более там нет. § 91, пункт ж.
У Фрамполь:
ТЕМ БОЛЕЕ ! , частица; разг.

Редко употребляется в функции вводного для выражения субъективного отношения к какому-либо факту, при желании подчеркнуть его значимость (интонационно выделяется): Теперь ты, надеюсь, убедился, что этот благородный рыбак не лгун и, тем более, не вор? (Л.Лагин); Мне, тем более, домой скоро (В.Короленко); Вот - солдат, но он не похож ни на одного из тех, кого я знаю, - ни на Сидорова, ни на вятича с парохода, ни, тем более, на Ермохина; он - больше человек, чем все они (М.Горький).

Обычно невводное, употребляется в функции усилительной частицы (произносится с повышением тона, без пауз), не обособляется: Я еще не знал тогда характера этого человека вполне, а уж: тем более его намерений (Ф.Достоевский); Но и в изображении героического Пушкин чуждается романтической приподнятости, какой бы то ни было идеализации и тем более мелодраматизма


В  грамматике однородные отношения могут дифференцироваться с помощью наречий, частиц и вводных слов. Но, как видно по большому количеству примеров, тем более в этой функции практически не применяется.
При анализе надо учитывать интонационные особенности предложения, так как выделить вводное слово в такой позиции  сложно. Соответственно, именно в роли частицы употребление тем более представляется обоснованным.
Статья о тем более

• Я думаю, что в этом предложении "тем более" является частицей со значением "особенно" (не вводными словами), поэтому в обособлении не нуждается.
"Употребляется для выделения или усиления важности последующей части высказывания".
Если не хочешь быть убийцей и тем более самоубийцей, то вариант один — найти какую-то среднюю дорожку, несмотря на риски.

ТЕМ БОЛЕЕ, частица и союз
1. Частица. То же, что 'особенно'. Не требует постановки знаков препинания.
Ты, жена, пойми одно – и от Айзады, и от Сабитжана тем более, пусть он и сын, мужчина, толку будет мало (Ч. Айтматов. И дольше века длится день)...
Если слова 'тем более' вводят присоединительную конструкцию с дополнительными замечаниями, вся конструкция выделяется знаками препинания, обычно запятыми.
Но по бездорожью лошадь идти не хотела, тем более через заросли, и ездовой, что-то ворча про себя, слез с повозки и взял коня под уздцы (В. Быков. Волчья стая).

• Примеры
Ну разве мог такой человек быть похитителем и тем более убийцей? (В. Айерс).
— Ладно, пусть будет так, но моя дочь никогда не была хулиганкой и тем более убийцей... (Ю. Ганин).
При этом Бирюков подчеркнул, что такие попытки и тем более суицид — страшное горе для родителей (из статьи).

Обособление не нужно.

Вводным словом тем более может быть в определенных позициях, как указано в Справочнике:

Тем более, от тифа сейчас нам большая угроза. Л. Кассиль, Кондуит и Швамбрания. Мне, тем более, домой скоро. В. Короленко, Чудная.

Во всех остальных вариантах обособления тем более нет, а постановка запятых делается в соответствии со структурой предложения.

Для решения задачи надо указать исходное предложение без частицы тем более:


Если не хочешь быть убийцей и самоубийцей, то вариант один — найти какую-то среднюю дорожку, несмотря на риски.
Союз И соединяет однородные сказуемые.
Примеры с однородными членами: и тем более
Обсуждение темы на форуме

Sharon, а разве по вашей ссылке "и тем более" все примеры с однородными членами? И разве все они правильные?

Не все, но многие. Смотреть надо, анализировать)  У союза И разная синтаксическая роль,  // А Карта слов не умеет различать правильное и неправильное, поэтому самим приходится проверять)  Но  все нюансы развивают мышление, так что польза есть)

Вы же сами сказали, что "решение практически однозначное, вариантов нет". И вдруг — надо анализировать, смотреть, проверять... И ещё из вашего ответа: "Союз И соединяет однородные сказуемые". Разве?

Я даю ссылку на ресурс, где целый пакет примеров по теме, но он вам не нравится.  А мне не нравится, когда в ответе есть примеры, а анализа нет. Грамматический анализ - вот что главное при постановке знаков, а вовсе не примеры.  Кстати, какая грамматическая основа в заданном предложении?  Об однозначности я дам отдельный ответ.
